# Java class inheritance and blocking superclass methods

Tags: java, class, inheritance, superclass

Im currently making a simple pluginable program. My problem is that I don't want to let plugin access all base-plugin fields/methods. For example:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin {
    private int x; //Mysterious x
    public abstract void update(); //update func that may need x, but can't change it
    protected final int getX() {return x;} //x accessor
}
```

And that would work unless you realize that there is no way to set x.

What can I do? I want to make subclass (plugin) unable to change x, but let it read the value. Value should be accesible at least once when creating (that would be enough).

EDIT: Constructor works in most cases, but what if I have for example:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin {
    private List<int> x; //Mysterious x
    public abstract void update(); //update func that may need x, but can't change it
    protected final List<int> getX() {return x;} //x accessor
    public BasePlugin(List<int> y) {x = y;}
}

public class Plugin {
    public Plugin(List<int> y)
    {
        super(y);
        y.remove(0); //Will it work?
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? that's works

Comment: Do you want it to be set at construction? If so, that's easy enough to solve.

Comment: I can't set X in any way. Or I just don't know how.

Comment: @MichaelMyers setting it at constructions is enough as I said (once when creating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abstract class is permitted to have a constructor, so you can create a parameterless constructor for BasePlugin:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin {
    private int x; //Mysterious x
    public BasePlugin() {
        x = 42;
    }
    public abstract void update(); //update func that may need x, but can't change it
    protected final int getX() {return x;} //x accessor
}
```

And now when a plugin is created, x is set to 42. You don't even need to make any code changes to the plugins to make them use this constructor.

---

To answer the edited question: If x is a List and you don't want the plugins to modify it, your constructor should be copying it and wrapping it in an [unmodifiable list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). Otherwise, any plugin can call `getX().add(myObject)`.

```
public BasePlugin(List<int> y) {
    List<int> temp = new ArrayList<int>();
    Collections.copy(temp, y); // shallow copy of the list
    this.x = Collections.unmodifiableList(temp);
}
```

Now if the plugin's constructor is

```
public Plugin(List<int> y)
{
    super(y);
    y.remove(0); //Will it work?
}
```

It will have no effect on the BasePlugin's list.

Comment: Okay. And what if parameter is more complex object like List? Then user can still edit it after the super(x).

Comment: @kittyPL: Lists are mutable, so if you have an accessor and don't want the plugins to modify the list, you'll have to wrap it in an [unmodifiable list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) anyway.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks! Accepting your answer, becouse it's just perfect, still upvoted other ones too becouse they also solve the first part.

Comment: @kittyPL take care that you can't modify your list even in basePlugin class, cause will throw `UnsopportedOperationException` if you try adding or removing

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor to get your property initialized by the subclasses:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin {
    private int x; //Mysterious x

    public BasePlugin(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public abstract void update(); //update func that may need x, but can't change it
    protected final int getX() {return x;} //x accessor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Constructor Injection.

```
public abstract class BasePlugin{

  private int x;

  public BasePlugin(int x){
   this.x=x;
  }

  public abstract void update(); //update func that may need x, but can't change it
  protected final int getX() {return x;} //x accessor

}
```

And in your childs

```
public class Plugin extends BasePlugin{


  public Plugin(int x){
    super(x);
  }

}
```

Comment: you have to implement your deep clone() method..or convert unmodifiableList